# boost::asio::async_accept is in a infinite loop

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am creating a TCP server using boost::asio. I am listening 9012 port(I know this port is available) and opening a socket from a java program as such:

```
public static main(String args[]) {
    Socket sock = new Socket("10.0.10.128",9012);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println(1);
    while(true){}
}
```

On C++ side:

```
void TCPServer::do_accept() {
    acceptor_obj.async_accept([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec, tcp::socket socket) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::make_shared<TCPSession>(std::move(socket))->start_async_read();
        }
        do_accept();
    });
}
```

I expected it to only create a single TCPSession however it is in an infinite loop constantly creating TCPSession/s. Can anyone tell me why this might be the case?

edit: acceptor_obj was missing method call /facepalm

Comment: You are calling `do_accept()` in the lambda so creating another acceptor and so on.

Comment: @Manuel But the second one should wait for a new TCP connection to be available before it calls the lambda.

Comment: I think @Manuel could be right here allthough he can't know unless he knows what `acceptor_obj` is. Please make a SSCCE/MVCE

Comment: @Manuel it was missing function call my bad

Comment: With that edit, the only explanation is: something is repeatedly connecting to that server.